# How to create a 3d cube with 8 different colored octants in power bi that you can drag around to rotate

Tags: powerbi, 3d, visualization

How to create a 3d cube with 8 different colored octants in power bi that you can drag around to rotate.

[image]

The cube should look something like this

Comment: Take a look at plotlyjs addin.